# complex harmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I have not been able to do this exercise since I do not understand well how to use the chain rule in this exercise, they could help me with the way to solve it...

Let $\phi :D\to D’$ be analytic and even twice continuously differentiable and $\eta: D’ \to \mathbb{R} $ twice continuously partial differentiable show 
if $\phi$ is conformal then $\eta$ is harmonic if and only if $\eta \circ \phi$ is harmonic.

Comment: What are $D$ and $D'$?

Comment: $D,D′  \subseteq  \mathbb{C}$

Comment: Do you know that analytic functions on open sets in $\mathbb C$  are infinitely differentiable and have continuous partial derivatives of all orders? You are assumption are superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :harmonicity is  a local property: a function is harmonic in an open set iff it is harmonic in some disk around each point. In an disk a function is harmonic iff it is the real part of an anlytic function. The result follows from this and the fact that composition if two analytic functions is analytic. [If $\phi$ is a conformal mapping then $\phi ^{-1}$ is also analytic].